# In what base system a given decimal-based number with no terminating decimal expansion can be represented in a finite string of digits?

Tags: number-theory

I was reading about precision floating numbers in the mpmath python module documentation and came across this https://mpmath.org/doc/current/contexts.html#arbitrary-precision-interval-arithmetic-iv:

> The fact that '0.1' results in an interval of nonzero width indicates
> that 1/10 cannot be represented using binary floating-point numbers at
> this precision level (in fact, it cannot be represented exactly at any
> precision).

This made me wonder if there's a way to determine in what base system a given decimal-based number with no terminating decimal expansion can be transferred in order to be represented in a finite string of digits.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.  Irrational numbers are irrational in allbases.  Do you possibly mean "it what base(s) does a given *rational* number have a terminating expansion?'  For instance, in base $3$  we have $\frac 13=.1_3$.

Comment: If the number is rational (e.g. $\frac{p}{q}$), take the base $q$.

Comment: @lulu you are right about the irrational, I've edited it.

Answer (score 3):

It helps to understand why a certain number is terminating or non-terminating in a given base. Let us take base $b$. If you express a number $n$ in base $b$ as:
$$n=d_kd_{k-1}\cdots d_0 \space . \space d_{-1}d_{-2}\cdots d_{-l}$$
then this is equivalent to saying:
$$n=\sum_{i=-l}^k d_i \cdot b^i \implies b^ln=\sum_{i=0}^{k+l} d_{i-l} b^i$$
Now, it is clear that it is necessary $b^ln$ to be an integer for some $l \in \mathbb{N}$ for $n$ to terminate in base $b$. This is clearly a sufficient condition as well since if $b^ln$ is an integer, it clearly terminates in base $b$ (since all integers terminate in all bases), and thus, when dividing $b^ln$ by $b^l$, since it is base $b$, only digits move across the decimal point.

Hence, we have proven that a number $n$ terminates in base $b$ if and only if there exists $l \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b^ln$ is an integer. This clearly cannot hold for irrational numbers $n$ since:
$$b^ln \in \mathbb{Z} \implies b^ln=t \implies n=\frac{t}{b^l}$$
where both $t$ and $b^l$ are non-zero integers, contradicting the fact that $n$ is irrational. Hence, irrational numbers are non-terminating in all bases.

Although, when you consider rational numbers, some rational numbers terminate in some bases but not in others. Consider the rational number $n=\frac{x}{y}$ in its simplest form. If $y$ has a prime factor $p$ that does not divide $b$, then no matter what $l$ you take, $b^ln$ will still have the prime factor $p$ in its denominator, and hence $b^ln$ cannot be an integer, which means that $n$ is non-terminating in base $b$.

If $y$ does not contain any such prime factor, then all prime factors of $y$ divide $b$. Define $l$ to be the largest power of a prime in the prime factorization of $y$. Then, it is clear that $b^ln$ is an integer since all the primes get cleared from the denominator. Hence, $n$ will terminate in base $b$.

Thus, a rational number is terminating in base $b$, if and only if for the denominator of $n$ in its simplest form, all its prime factors are also prime factors of $b$.

Comment: I like this explanation... The last paragraph though seems to me like it has some syntactical error and prevents me from grasping the meaning...
Should it be "if and only if the denominator of n _is_ in its simplest form" ? There seems to be a lack of continuity in the secondary sentence between the commas. (it might have to do with me not being a native English speaker)

Comment: @Demis That phrasing is fine, because OP is focusing on "the denominator of $n$ in its simplest form". It might be easier had Haran defined $ n = i/j, \gcd(i,j) = 1$, in which case $j$ has the desired definition. Then, the statement is  "iff all prime factors of $j$ are also prime factors of $b$".

Comment: @CalvinLin Maybe the set of constrictions, statements and conditions should be provided in a form of steps like bullets rather a single phrase. (Maybe it's clearer for me having studied IT). For me the last statement unfolds to : A rational number is terminating in base b if - 1) the denominator of n is in its simplest form 2) all its prime factors are also prime factors of b.

Comment: The "only if (all its ...)" part seems weird, and might be a result of repeated editing of that statement. If it was phrased as " if and only if for the denominator of $n$ in its simplest form, all its prime factors are also prime factors of $b$", does that clear things up / have the same interpretation as my statement? 
.

Comment: @Demis Inputs taken and edit made, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @CalvinLin Inputs taken and edit made, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by 'base system'. In base $\pi$, for instance, the units column is $1$, meaning that the 'tens' column is $\pi$, and so on. $\pi$ can be represented as $10$ in base $\pi$. However, if you require that the base is an integer, then no, there isn't an irrational number that can be written as a finite string. We can prove this by contraposition. If a number $n$ has a finite number of digits, then we can write the digits that come after the decimal point as
$$
.d_1d_2d_3\ldots d_k \, .
$$
This means that $$n=\text{integer part + }(b^{-1} \cdot d_1)+(b^{-2}\cdot d_2)+(b^{-3}\cdot d_3)+\ldots+(b^{-k}\cdot d_k) \, .$$The sum of finitely many rationals is rational. Hence, finite number of digits $\implies$ the number is rational. This means that irrational numbers can't have finitely many digits, and so they must have infinitely many digits.

Comment: By "base system" I mean systems like binary, hexadecimal etc... I had no idea that there was a way to have a system based on non integers or even transcendent numbers ... by saying "π can be represented as 10 in base π" you are essentially mapping a set of infinite members on an other of the same magnitude right ?

Comment: @Demis If we are talking about base systems like binary or hexadecimal, then there is no way to write an irrational number with finitely many digits, as shown by my proof is above (please ask if you have any questions about it). I don't know what you mean when you say 'you are essentially mapping a set of infinite members on an other of the same magnitude right?'.

Comment: There's been a misunderstanding about the irrational part which is my fault coping the title from a question that had been deleted prior to editing for  clarification.
I assumed that by saying "π  can be represented as 10 in base π" then 1/π is 1 in base π , 2/π is 2 in base π etc ... It's OK, I got it wrong and now I get what you were saying.

Comment: @Demis Just to be clear: $1$ is just $1$ in *any* base system. In base $\pi$, the digits that come after the decimal point are multiples of $1/\pi$, $1/\pi^2$, etc.

Comment: You said "The sum of finitely many rationals is rational." Does that mean that the sum of infinitely many rationals can be an irrational number or you said that to avoid classifying an infinite number as irrational ?

Comment: @Demis Yes, it can be. For example, $\pi = 3 + 0.1 + 0.04 + 0.005 + 0.0009 + \cdots $. Be careful, though. What we call an infinite sum is really just the limit of a finite sum: $$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}S_r := \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r=0}^{n}S_r \, .$$If any of this didn't make sense to you, just let me know.